# Contact page - issue with "My logins" description about navigation to the section

Tags: bug, design, contact, my-logins

In the Meta Stack Exchange [Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)'s, Contact support section, when selecting the option as "I need to add or remove login credentials", there is a popup opened.

[image: option]

In that, I see the description as "Open up your [user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) page and click “my logins” in the top right", but currently there is no such option in the profile page.

[image: contact]

Seems it was referred the old UI screen as below, can the description be updated to matching with the new UI. (Edit profile and settings -> My Logins)

[image: old]